# Posting ScoreLoop score in Facebook

Tags: android, scoreloop

I'm Using ScoreLoop.

How can I post Scores in a Facebook and twitter using the ScoreLoop SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have downloaded the Scoreloop SDK, you have the option to use the ScoreloopUI or the ScoreloopCore. ScoreloopUI comes with the ready-built UI along with the core APIs (this will be a quick start for developers). ScoreloopCore has the Core APIs which developers can use but here developers have to write their own UI.

Most of the developers use the ScoreloopUI, so, I am assuming you would also be using the ScoreloopUI. In the downloaded Scoreloop SDK package, there is a docs folder, inside that, please open up ScoreloopUI_doc.html and navigate to Integration Guide - Advanced Integration - Posting Scores to Social Networks. There you will find the steps you need to integrate Social network posting into your app.

In case you come across any issues, please post your query on support.scoreloop.com and the support team would help you out.

Thanks,
Prenitha